# Struct with bit fields reordering?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I wrote a struct with anonymous struct and uninon:

byte is `typedef unsigned char byte`

```
struct dns_flags
{
    union 
    {
        struct 
        {
            byte QR : 1;
            byte opCode : 4; 
            byte AA : 1;
            byte TC : 1;
            byte RD : 1;
            byte RA : 1;
            byte zero : 3; 
            byte rcode : 4; 
        };

        uint16_t flagsValue; 
    };

};
```

Which represents DNS protocol flags.

I used `#pragma pack(push,1)`  and while `sizeof(dns_flags) == 2` when `flagsValue == 0x8180`;  then `rcode = 8`. So I wonder about the layout of the struct in memory: The `rcode` nibble is the higher one?! that just doesn't make any sense... working with VS2012

Guy

Comment: The order of the bits depends on whether you're big-endian or little-endian. Take a look at the Linux header file for TCP packets, you'll see it has a conditional for endianness.

Comment: By the way, what's the definition of `byte`? (the reader shouldn't have to guess...). _Edit: Ok._

Comment: byte is `typedef unsigned char byte`

Comment: @Barmar i did the ntohs trick... it's not the case

Comment: what is the rcode if flagsValue == 0x8040 ?

Comment: @DieterLücking: it doesn't changes; but if it's 4080 rcode == 4

Comment: That is little endian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual order of bitfields isn't specified in the standard. It is entirely up to the compiler to do what it likes (as long as it does it the same way each time). I think most compilers follow the byte-order of the machine itself (so the first field is the lowest bit in a little endian machine, and the highest bit in a big endian machine), but this is not guaranteed, just "convention".

Comment: Most machines don't have "bit order"; a byte is 8 bits, but there's no order to it.  And at least in C, the order can't be arbitrary; it must allocate the bitfields in the order they are specified (but whether from high bit to low or vice versa isn't specified, nor is where any padding goes).  Finally, I'm pretty sure that I've seen one compiler that would make all `struct` with bitfields at least 32 bits, which will sort of defeat what he is trying to do anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze about the 32bit padding -> the sizeof(dns_flags) is 2.

Comment: I think what James means is that SOME compiler(s) will use a 32-bit word for any size bitfield - again, it is ineed up to the compiler to decide how much space the whole structure uses. In other words, if you want reasonably portable code, don't use bitfields...

Answer (score 3):

Do not use bit fields in a union to address bits of an unsigned integer (the implementation has compiler and machine dependencies). A compatible solution:

```
struct dns_flags {
    uint16_t flagsValue; 
    uint16_t qr() const { return flagsValue & 1; }
    ...
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure... I also tried without the uninon and struct.. (just one struct with bit fields)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what standard mandates, you can refer to Mats Peterson's answer, but this is how memory  is layed out for this struct.

It is because your machine is little Endian and the value `0x8180` gets stored as `8081` i.e. lower byte is `0x80` at lower address and higher byte is `0x81` at higher address.

`(LB)`(0x80) bytes (7->0)  = 0x80

`(HB)`(0x81) bytes (15->8) = 0x81

```
  This forms your lower byte (0x80)
byte QR : 1;        <------- Lower Address    --> ( bit 0)  
byte opCode : 4;                              --> ( bits 1,2,3,4)
byte AA : 1;                                  --> ( bit 5)
byte TC : 1;                                  --> ( bit 6)
byte RD : 1;                                  --> ( bit 7)

And this is the higher byte (0x81)
byte RA : 1;                                  --# (bit 8)
byte zero : 3;                                --# (bits 9,10,11)
byte rcode : 4;     <------- Higher Address   --# (bits 12,13,14,15)
```

If you  check the value of `RA` it should be one because it is at bit position `8` and  `8th` bit in `0x8180` is `1`(converted to `int` type).

And it the value written is `0x8280` then `RA` will have value `0` and `zero` will have `1`.